# How to implement scrollViewDidScroll in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm having a problem where when I call the `scrollViewDidScroll` method in my subclass of `UIScrollView` nothing happens. Here is my code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "ScrollView.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    CGRect screenRect = [[self window] bounds];

    ScrollView *scrollView = [[ScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    [[self window] addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView setContentSize:screenRect.size];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**ScrollView.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ScrollView.h"

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        [super addSubview:imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"%f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

Comment: did you add scrollView.delegate=self; ??

Comment: well, i would initialize and put the scrollView in the viewDidLoad of the page you want it on, and then put it there, try just adding it to the viewDidLoad of the page you want it on

Comment: actually, just try putting it in the initWithFrame, might work there

Comment: Why do you want scroll view in app delegate?
I don't think thats the good choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

add

```
self.delegate = self;
```

or in AppDelegate.m,after scrollview inited, add this code

```
scrollview.delegate = self;
```

of course, you must implements the delegate method

```
scrollViewDidScroll:
```

and don't forgot add below code in AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 6):

> For iOS10, SWift 3.0 implement scrollViewDidScroll on UIScrollView

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

//In viewDidLoad Set delegate method to self.

@IBOutlet var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mainScrollView.delegate = self

}
//And finally you implement the methods you want your class to get.
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    // This will be called every time the user scrolls the scroll view with their finger
    // so each time this is called, contentOffset should be different.

    print(self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y)

    //Additional workaround here.
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Step 1:  Create Delegate for UIViewController Class:

```
  @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Step 2: Then add Delegate for your `UIScrollView` object:

```
  scrollview.delegate = self;
```

Step 3:  Implements Delegate methods as follow:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     // Do your stuff here...
     // You can also track the direction of UIScrollView here....
     // to check the y position use scrollView.contentOffset.y
 }
```

Here you go.  With the help of above 3 steps you can integrate `ScrollViewDidScroll` method into our `Objective-C` Class.